# Copying a folder from one server to another using scp

Tags: linux, scp

I am using PuTTY. I am trying to copy a folder from one server to another server in Linux.
But I am getting this error on to the PuTTY console as

```
myfolder: Not a regular file
```

Is it possible to copy a folder using `scp`?

It worked on a zip file when I tried it earlier on.

Comment: if you are using windows, try winscp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `scp -r`. It should do the trick.